# Dynamic menus in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to create some dynamic menus in a VS2010 SDI application I'm writing. I've seen this, but don't really understand it
[Dynamic menu using mfc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673546/dynamic-menu-using-mfc)

At the moment, I've no idea how to even use GetMenu to get a handle to the menu from my Doc file. I'm trying this, but it says GetMenu doesn't take zero arguments, even though many examples I've seen clearly show this.

```
CMenu *menu = GetMenu();


        menu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, ID_HIDE, _T("Text"));
```

All I want to do is add a list of files underneath a sub-menu, selected from a database (hence the dynamic part), so a user can select the one they want to work on.

Thanks,
James

Comment: I believe it takes a `HWND` so it knows which menu to get.

Comment: Hi,If you can tell me how I'd go about doing that I'd very grateful?

Comment: You could use a variety of things, including `FindWindow` to get the handle. I'm not sure what all mfc offers for that, but then you can just pass the `HWND` in. For the submenus, you can use `GetSubMenu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `GetMenu` from within a window class derived from `CWnd`, you'll be calling `CWnd::GetMenu` and it will not require a window handle. If you're calling it from anywhere else you will get `::GetMenu(HWND)` and you will need to pass a window handle. You can get the handle from any CWnd object with its `m_hWnd` member or by calling `GetSafeHwnd()` on it.

Comment: I found this site which is very useful for showing how to get at teh different object types, http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?281430-MFC-Doc-View-How-to-obtain-a-pointer-to-various-objects