# use command range for dynamic menu

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

This may be very basic question but as newbie don't understand the reason,Basically i want popup menu on tree control like,On right click of tree control one menu will pop up and on basic of this menu other functionality proceed.For that purpose i used following code,

in .h file,

```
#define NEW_RELAY_MENU_START                    WM_USER + 1
#define NEW_RELAY_MENU_END                  WM_USER + 256
```

in .cpp file

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCtrlModDefDlgTree, CTreeCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(TVN_SELCHANGED, OnSelChangedTreeCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_RCLICK, &CCtrlModDefDlgTree::OnNMRClick)
    ON_COMMAND_RANGE(NEW_RELAY_MENU_START,NEW_RELAY_MENU_END,CCtrlModDefDlgTree::OnNewMenu)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CCtrlModDefDlgTree::CCtrlModDefDlgTree()
{
    NumberOfRelays.RemoveAll();
    NumberOfRelays.Add(L"MENU1");
    NumberOfRelays.Add(L"MENU2");
    NumberOfRelays.Add(L"MENU3");
    NumberOfRelays.Add(L"MENU4");
    NumberOfRelays.Add(L"MENU5);
    NumberOfRelays.Add(L"MENU6");   
}
void CCtrlModDefDlgTree::OnNMRClick(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
     /* Get the cursor position for this message */ 
    DWORD dwPos = GetMessagePos(); 
    /* Convert the co-ords into a CPoint structure */ 
    CPoint pt( GET_X_LPARAM( dwPos ), GET_Y_LPARAM ( dwPos ) ); 
    CPoint spt; 
    spt = pt; 
    /* convert to screen co-ords for the hittesting to work */ 
    ScreenToClient( &spt ); 
    UINT test; 
    HTREEITEM hti = HitTest( spt, &test ); 
    if ( hti != NULL  ) 
    { 
            /* Is the click atcually *on* the item? */ 
            if ( test & TVHT_ONITEM ) 
            { 
                    /* Do the normal context menu stuff */ 
                    ShowPopupMenu(  pt ); 
            } 
    } 
    *pResult = 0; 
}
void CCtrlModDefDlgTree::ShowPopupMenu( CPoint& point )
{
        if (point.x == -1 && point.y == -1)
        {
            //keystroke invocation
            CRect rect;
            GetClientRect(rect);
            ClientToScreen(rect);
            point = rect.TopLeft();
            point.Offset(5, 5);
        }

        //create a menu object for main menu
        CMenu *menu    = new CMenu();
        menu->CreatePopupMenu();

        //another menu object for submenu
        CMenu *subMenu = new CMenu();
        subMenu->CreatePopupMenu();
        for(int __index = 0;__index<NumberOfRelays.GetCount();__index++)
        {
            subMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, NEW_RELAY_MENU_START+__index, NumberOfRelays.ElementAt(__index));
        }
        //append submenu to menu
        menu->AppendMenu(MF_POPUP|MF_STRING, (UINT)subMenu->m_hMenu,  _T("New Menu") );
        ASSERT(menu != NULL);
        CWnd* pWndPopupOwner = this;
        while (pWndPopupOwner->GetStyle() & WS_CHILD)
            pWndPopupOwner = pWndPopupOwner->GetParent();
        menu->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y,
            pWndPopupOwner);
}

void CCtrlModDefDlgTree::OnNewMenu(UINT nID)
{
}
```

But my OnNewMenu() function is not called on menu click.Even all menus are by default enable.What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added the command range to the message map for the tree control, but you're not using the tree control as the owner window for the menu.

```
CWnd* pWndPopupOwner = this;
while (pWndPopupOwner->GetStyle() & WS_CHILD)
    pWndPopupOwner = pWndPopupOwner->GetParent();
```

This will find the top-level window and use it as the popup's owner, which means the `WM_COMMAND` messages from the popup will go to the top-level window rather than the tree. You need to add the command range to that window's message map.

Alternatively, you can use the `TPM_RETURNCMD` flag with `TrackPopupMenu` which will return the selected command ID, and then invoke your `OnNewMenu()` function yourself:

```
int iID = menu->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD, 
            point.x, point.y, pWndPopupOwner);
if (iID) OnNewMenu(iID);
```

Comment: alternative is great!!