# How to add submenu dynamically in mfc

Tags: mfc

I have added a menu in my windows program using resource editor now I want to add a submenu under some specific condition.
Below is piece of my code.

This is my **Menu.h** file

## include

class CmainWn : public CFrameWnd

{

public :CmainWn();

DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

afx_msg void OnAB();

};

class CApp : public CWinApp

{

public : BOOL InitInstance();

};

This is my **Menu.cpp**

## include"Menu.h"

## include"resource.h"

CmainWn ::CmainWn()

{

```
Create(NULL,"Menu Testing",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,rectDefault,NULL,(LPCTSTR)IDR_MENU1);
```

}

BOOL CApp :: InitInstance()

{

```
m_pMainWnd=new CmainWn();

m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);

m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();

return true;
```

}

void CmainWn::OnAB()

{

```
AfxMessageBox("Hello");
```

}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CmainWn,CFrameWnd)

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_A_B, &CmainWn::OnAB)
```

END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CApp App;

As you can see the code I have created main menu named A and one submenu named B.
I want to add one menu dynamically under B. How to do it ?

Comment: Your question is a poorly formatted version of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28690886/1889329) (asked 4 hours ago).

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673546/dynamic-menu-using-mfc

Comment: @GingerJack yes I have gone through that and able to create dynamic menu at run time but not able to append as submenu item in my main menu.

Comment: I recommend you to read the `OnInitMenuPopup` documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable: Your comment does not make sense anymore, as«s its link became dead.

Comment: @sergiol: It's dead, unless you have [enough reputation to see deleted content](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). I can still see the question very well by following the link.

Answer (score -2):

Sample code that has to be added to your windows resource file (projectname.rc)

```
IDR_MENU1 MENU 
BEGIN
      POPUP "Main menu"
       BEGIN
           MENUITEM "Menu Item 1", ID_WINDOWS_TEST
           POPUP "Sub Menu"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "Sub Menu item 1",ID_WIN_TEXT
        END
    END
END
```

Viewing this in resource view would display something like this
[image]

Comment: This doesn't add menu entries dynamically.